# JBOSS AS 7.1.1 listinUseConnections() method in CachedConnectionManager MBean?

Tags: java, jboss, connection, jboss7.x, connection-pooling

How  to see the unclosed connections along with their Stacktraces, the listinUseConnections() method from the CachedConnectionManager MBean which can be invoked from the JMX-console. How to see this  in Jboss AS 7.1.1 ?
Any Idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a post on [Detecting and closing leaked connections in JBoss 7.1](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DetectingAndClosingLeakedConnectionsInJBoss71)  .

Comment: Do you have compiled version's of these patches, patch1 for IronJacamar and patch2 for as7 jca connector?